# Get the data from sensor and save it somewhere

Tags: android, sqlite, bluetooth

I'm using a sensor connected via Bluetooth who **sends info about heart rate, heart beat number, distance, speed and strides**.

I've done it, it shows me info about that 5 facts but **I don't know how to save them**.The sensor sends info very often, about 1 time per second.

I **must write it in SQLite** and insert data with something that I think is called 'bulk insert' because it works faster than inserting every time the sensor sends data. So, the data must be saved somewhere until the bulk insert into SQLite.

This is my code so far which gets data in real time from the sensor:

```
import java.util.Set;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



    public class hxmDemo extends Activity {


        private static final String TAG = "hxmDemo";


        private TextView mTitle;
        private TextView mStatus;

        private String mHxMName = null;
        private String mHxMAddress = null;

        private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;


        private HxmService mHxmService = null;

private void connectToHxm() {

    mStatus.setText(R.string.connecting);


    if (mHxmService == null) 
        setupHrm();

    if ( getFirstConnectedHxm() ) {
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mHxMAddress);
        mHxmService.connect(device);    // Attempt to connect to the device
    } else {
        mStatus.setText(R.string.nonePaired);           
    }

}


    private boolean getFirstConnectedHxm() {


        mHxMAddress = null;     
        mHxMName = null;


        BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


        Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();


        if (bondedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : bondedDevices) {
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                if ( deviceName.startsWith("HXM") ) {

                    mHxMAddress = device.getAddress();
                    mHxMName = device.getName();
                    Log.d(TAG,"getFirstConnectedHxm() found a device whose name starts with 'HXM', its name is "+mHxMName+" and its address is ++mHxMAddress");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }





        return (mHxMAddress != null);
   }




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");


    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.rawdata);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);


    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    if ( mTitle == null ) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went very wrong, missing resource, rebuild the application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }            


    mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
    if ( mStatus == null ) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went very wrong, missing resource, rebuild the application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }            


    mTitle.setText(R.string.hxmDemoAppName);
    mStatus.setText(R.string.initializing);



mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeMessage.class);
startActivityForResult( intent , 1 );


if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available or not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    mStatus.setText(R.string.noBluetooth);

 } else {

    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        mStatus.setText(R.string.btNotEnabled);
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart: Blueooth adapter detected, but it's not enabled");
    } else {
        mStatus.setText(R.string.connecting);
        connectToHxm();


       }
     }        
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");


    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null ) {
        // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
        // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult     
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            mStatus.setText(R.string.btNotEnabled);
            Log.d(TAG, "onStart: Blueooth adapter detected, but it's not enabled");
        }
    } else {
        mStatus.setText(R.string.noBluetooth);
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart: No blueooth adapter detected, it needs to be present and enabled");
    }

}

@Override
public synchronized void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume");

    // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
    // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
    // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
    if (mHxmService != null) {

        if (mHxmService.getState() == R.string.HXM_SERVICE_RESTING) {
          // Start the Bluetooth scale services
          mHxmService.start();
        }
    }
}

private void setupHrm() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupScale:");

    // Initialize the service to perform bluetooth connections
    mHxmService = new HxmService(this, mHandler);
}

@Override
public synchronized void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.e(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.e(TAG, "-- ON STOP --");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Stop the Bluetooth chat services
    if (mHxmService != null) mHxmService.stop();
    Log.e(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");
}


private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case R.string.HXM_SERVICE_MSG_STATE: 
            Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage():  MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
            switch (msg.arg1) {
                case R.string.HXM_SERVICE_CONNECTED:
                    if ((mStatus != null) && (mHxMName != null)) {
                        mStatus.setText(R.string.connectedTo);
                        mStatus.append(mHxMName);
                    }
                    break;

                case R.string.HXM_SERVICE_CONNECTING:
                    mStatus.setText(R.string.connecting);
                    break;

                case R.string.HXM_SERVICE_RESTING:
                    if (mStatus != null ) {
                        mStatus.setText(R.string.notConnected);
                    }
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case R.string.HXM_SERVICE_MSG_READ: {

            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            HrmReading hrm = new HrmReading( readBuf );
            hrm.displayRaw();
            break;
        }

        case R.string.HXM_SERVICE_MSG_TOAST:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(null),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.scan:
            connectToHxm();
            return true;

        case R.id.quit:
            finish();
            return true;

        case R.id.about: {
            /*
             * Start the activity that displays our welcome message
             */
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeMessage.class);
            startActivityForResult( intent , 1 );
            break;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + requestCode);

    switch(requestCode)
    {  

        case 1:
            break;

    }             
}

public class HrmReading {
    public final int STX = 0x02;
    public final int MSGID = 0x26;
    public final int DLC = 55;
    public final int ETX = 0x03;

    private static final String TAG = "HrmReading";


    int heartRate;
    int heartBeatNumber;

    long distance;
    long speed;
    byte strides;    

    public HrmReading (byte[] buffer) {
        int bufferIndex = 0;

        Log.d ( TAG, "HrmReading being built from byte buffer");

        try {

            heartRate           = (int)(0x000000FF & (int)(buffer[bufferIndex++]));
            heartBeatNumber     = (int)(0x000000FF & (int)(buffer[bufferIndex++]));
            distance            = (long) (int)((0x000000FF & (int)buffer[bufferIndex++]) | (int)(0x000000FF & (int)buffer[bufferIndex++])<< 8);
            speed               = (long) (int)((0x000000FF & (int)buffer[bufferIndex++]) | (int)(0x000000FF & (int)buffer[bufferIndex++])<< 8);
            strides             = buffer[bufferIndex++];

        } catch (Exception e) {
            /*
             * An exception should only happen if the buffer is too short and we walk off the end of the bytes,
             * because of the way we read the bytes from the device this should never happen, but just in case
             * we'll catch the exception
             */
            Log.d(TAG, "Failure building HrmReading from byte buffer, probably an incopmplete or corrupted buffer");
        }


        Log.d(TAG, "Building HrmReading from byte buffer complete, consumed " + bufferIndex + " bytes in the process");

        dump();
        }



        private void displayRaw() {       

            display ( R.id.heartRate, (int)heartRate );
            display ( R.id.heartBeatNumber,  (int)heartBeatNumber );
            display ( R.id.distance,   distance );
            display ( R.id.speed,   speed );
            display ( R.id.strides,  (int)strides );

        }    

    public void dump() {

            Log.d(TAG,"...heartRate "+ ( heartRate ));
            Log.d(TAG,"...heartBeatNumber "+ ( heartBeatNumber ));
            Log.d(TAG,"...distance "+ (  distance ));
            Log.d(TAG,"...speed "+ (  speed ));
            Log.d(TAG,"...strides "+ ( strides ));

    }    


    private void display  ( int nField, int d ) {   
        String INT_FORMAT = "%d";

        String s = String.format(INT_FORMAT, d);

        display( nField, s  );
    }


    private void display  ( int nField, long d ) {   
        String INT_FORMAT = "%d";

        String s = String.format(INT_FORMAT, d);

        display( nField, s  );
    }


    private void display ( int nField, CharSequence  str  ) {
        TextView tvw = (TextView) findViewById(nField);
        if ( tvw != null )
            tvw.setText(str);
        }
    }          
}
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is few steps, which you have to make:

1. Create your own class by extending #SQLiteOpenHelper - it will help you to handle your data base
2. Override #onCreate method - it will were you will execute sql request to create data base. I recommend to move name of keys for columns where you will store above data as static ariables, e.g:

   ```
   public static final class db {

     public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "data_table";

     public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
     public static final String KEY_HEART_RATE = "heart_rate";
     public static final String KEY_HEART_BEAT_NUMBER = "heart_beat_number";
     public static final String KEY_DISTANCE = "distance";
     public static final String KEY_SPEED = "speed";
     public static final String KEY_STRIDER = "strides";

     public static final String CREATE_DATA_TABLE =
     "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" 
       + KEY_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
       + KEY_HEART_RATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
       + KEY_HEART_BEAT_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
       + KEY_DISTANCE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
       + KEY_SPEED + " TEXT NOT NULL, " 
       + KEY_STRIDER + " TEXT NOT NULL");
   ```

and #onCreate may looks like it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  try {
    db.execSQL(CSConfig.db.db.CREATE_DATA_TABLE);
  } catch (SQLiteException e) {
    //Can not create table:
  }
}
```

3.Add method to insert yours data and call everytime when you need save data to db:

```
     public final void insertNewData(String heartRate, String heartBeatNumber, String distance, String speed, String stider, ) {

       ContentValues dataRowValues = new ContentValues();
       dataRowValues.put(CSConfig.db.db.KEY_HEART_RATE, heartRate);
       dataRowValues.put(CSConfig.db.db.KEY_HEART_BEAT_NUMBER, heartBeatNumber);
       dataRowValues.put(CSConfig.db.db.KEY_DISTANCE, distance);
       dataRowValues.put(CSConfig.db.db.KEY_SPEED, speed);
       dataRowValues.put(CSConfig.db.db.KEY_STRIDER, strider);

       insert(CSConfig.db.db.DATABASE_TABLE, null, dataRowValues);
     }
```

PS. I've omitted details about opening access to database. You can find more details e.g. [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)