# How to send data to another activity without opening it

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, send

I want to be able to data from activity a to activity b without opening activity b, I want to be able to go back to activity b later on and see the data displayed also i want the data(text) to stay even if the phone is turned off or the app is closed.

I have already tried using intents and shared-preference but the examples I have seen all require me to go to activity b.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Answer (score 2):

You should store data somewhere else - e.g. in SQLite data base, static global model or SharedPreferences. In activity B apply changes to your data and read it at activity A onResume() method.

**Edit**

You can check how to save and read data from database, e.g. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24864791/2004186), where I've described how to create database and save data from sensors. To read data from DB use e.g. rawQuery() - [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#sqliteoverview_rawquery) you can find some details.

Comment: any examples on how i can do this

Answer (score 0):

you must use SqLite database or use shared preference

check this links :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

example off SqLite database :

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences don't necessarily require you to go to activity B. It's basically just letting you access a file easily and you can do that from any activity. For example, create these methods in activity A:

```
public String getPreference() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("preferenceName", 0);
    return sp.getString("preferenceKeyValue", "default value if no preference is found");
}
public void setPreference(String data) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("preferenceName", 0).edit();
    editor.putString("preferenceKeyValue", data).commit();
}
```

And then call them like this:

```
setPreference("data for activity B");
// later on...
String data = getPreference();
```

That example uses strings, but you can save any of the following data: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings.

Here are the methods modified to your specific situation (better naming):

```
public String getActivityBData() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Activity B Data", 0);
    return sp.getString("data", "There is no data yet!");
}
public void setActivityBData(String str) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Activity B Data", 0).edit();
    editor.putString("data", str).commit();
}
```

You can also put these methods in your activity B class and access them like that. This data saved is not specific to any activity.

Comment: how do i get the data onto the second activity

Comment: It doesn't need to be "on" the second activity. What you're saying you want to do is impossible and unnecessary.